# How to make an apt-get install command

Tags: downloads

Am I able to make one of those "apt-get install program" codes that you use in terminal to download a program from my website?  If so, how?

Comment: check this article `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool`

Comment: Are you thinking of a link from your website that triggers installation of already available package in ubuntu repo? If not,  you can do as dropbox and link to deb files which opens in software centre too or consider having a PPA.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you don't know what `apt-get` does. It basically uses your software repositories to install `.deb` packages. If you want to download something from the internet using the command line, you should use the `wget` command.